# Focus hell on Gnome

Tags: linux, gnome, user-experience

I am using lastest Pop!_OS with gnome-shell. And I came across a focus problem. The "Window is Ready" window is not working properly. The problem is that often after applications finish working on some difficult task, they immediately take focus on themselves, which often causes unwanted clicks or key combinations. It is logical that at such a moment the same "Window is ready" is called, but it almost never works and is called only for a couple of system applications. How can this problem be solved? Possibility of some kind of extension or setting in the gnome?